# XPath to navigate graph structure encoded in XML

Tags: xml, xpath, xquery

I have a graph-like structure encoded in XML. Directed acyclic graph, to be precise.
The nodes are uniquely identified and have encoded successor-predecessor relationships.

Is it possible to construct an XQuery or XPath function, which navigates the graph to find first node, which satisfies a simple condition?

To be more precise, let's take the following XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <obj>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>FINDME</name>
        <relations>
            <successor>2</successor>
        </relations>
    </obj>
    <obj>
        <id>2</id>
        <relations>
            <predecessor>1</predecessor>
            <successor>3</successor>
        </relations>
    </obj>
    <obj>
        <id>3</id>
        <relations>
            <predecessor>2</predecessor> 
        </relations>
    </obj>
</doc>
```

Let's assume, the current node is 3.
I want to find a predecessor node's id, which has a name tag equal to "FINDME".
To do that, I can use following XPath:

```xpath
/doc/obj[name='FINDME'
      and id=/doc/obj[
          id=/doc/obj[
               id=3
               ]/relations/predecessor
           ]/relations/predecessor
       ]/id
```

Is it possible to generalize the query to handle arbitrary levels of relationship?

---

**EDIT**: joemfb answer does exactly answer this question. I have an additional request, could it handle more than one predecessor for a node and return any node not more than once?

So, it would work for following example as well:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<doc>
    <obj>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>FINDME</name>
        <relations>
            <successor>2</successor>
            <successor>4</successor>
        </relations>
    </obj>
    <obj>
        <id>4</id>
        <relations>
            <successor>2</successor>
            <predecessor>1</predecessor>
        </relations>
    </obj>
    <obj>
        <id>2</id>
        <relations>
            <predecessor>1</predecessor>
            <predecessor>4</predecessor>
            <successor>3</successor>
        </relations>
    </obj>
    <obj>
        <id>3</id>
        <relations>
            <predecessor>2</predecessor> 
        </relations>
    </obj>
</doc>
```

Comment: What do you mean by arbitrary levels of relationship? What part of the structure is arbitrary, or arbitrarily nested?

Comment: The XPath query I provided as an example will find only predecessor, of a predecessor of provided node... I would liike to handle "all predecessors"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly, you want to find predecessors of predecessors, as long as they exist. That's a perfect application for a recursive function.

Here's an XQuery solution:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare function local:predecessors($doc, $node)
{
  let $immediate-predecessor := $doc/doc/obj[id = $node/relations/predecessor]
  return
    if (fn:exists($immediate-predecessor))
    then (
      $immediate-predecessor,
      local:predecessors($doc, $immediate-predecessor)
    )
    else ()
};

let $doc := document { (: your doc ... :) }
let $results := local:predecessors($doc, $doc/doc/obj[id eq "3"])
return element results { $results intersect $results }
```

**Update**:

To support multiple `predecessor` elements, the predicate `[id = $node/relations/predecessor]` needs the general comparison operator `=`, which supports sequences in either operand, as opposed to the value comparison operator `eq`.

To return distinct nodes, we can use the [`intersect` operator](http://www.w3.org/TR/xquery/#combining_seq), which returns a sequence of unique nodes common to both operands (I could've also used `union` which similarly returns unique nodes).

I've tested these changes in Saxon HE:

```
java -cp /usr/local/Cellar/saxon/9.5.1.6/libexec/saxon9he.jar \
  net.sf.saxon.Query -q:test.xq | xmllint --format -
```

Comment: I think, this answers my question exactly! I can start out with this. If I run it on my real diagram, I get XPTY0004: A sequence of more than one item is not allowed as the second operand of 'eq'. Could You help me out with that as well?

Comment: ...I think it works if I replace "eq" with an "=" operator directly.

Comment: But then again, it returns the node with id 1 twice! Is it possible to have it distinct?

Comment: What XPath/XQuery processor are you using?

Comment: I'm using the Oxygen XML Developer with the included Saxon engine (the one which runs standard XQuery 1.0 queries)

Comment: I've updated my answer to support your additional requirements, and tested the query in Saxon HE.